# Connect a SharePoint workflow to a host list using visual studio for office 365

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, office365-apps

I am using office 365
Using Visual studio  2012 can i create a workflow project that connects to the host list in the host web and not the list in the app web.

Can I achieve this without using remote event receivers  and windows azure services. Is there a any workaround for this issue.